# Apostrophe causes Node SQL application to crash

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, database

I've got an application that uses sqlite3 and Node/Express. There is a search bar in the application that queries a database, however when ' or " is entered it crashes the whole page. I understand it's a reserved character in SQL, however I'd prefer if when entered an SQL error message was rendered on the page rather than it being crashed entirely.

When a regular input is put in after (e.g. banana), it doesn't work and continues to crash the page. Any ideas why?

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

and the code:

app.js

```
    ...
    var query = "SELECT * FROM tab WHERE name = '" + req.query.name + "'"
    db.all(query, (error, rows) => {
            res.render(__dirname + '/views/search.ejs', {data:rows, msg:req.query.name + " is available!"})
    })
    ...
```

index.html (the search bar)

```
                <form id="search_form" name="gs" method="get" action="search">
                <div class="searchText">
                  
                  <input type="text" name="name" class="searchText" id="searchText" placeholder="Enter your name here..." autocomplete="on">
                </div>
                    <input type="submit" name="results" class="main-button" value="Search Now">
                 </form>
```

search.ejs (what displays output from the database)

```
              <span><%- msg %></span>
              <h2>Check out our x</h2>
              <table class="styled-table">
              <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>x</th>
                <th>y</th>
              </tr>
              </thead>
              <% data.forEach(function(dat) { %>
                <tr>
                  <td><%= dat.name %></td>
                  <td>$<%= dat.var %>/yr</td>
                </tr>
              <% }); %>
              </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use single or double apostrophes with a variable in your SQL statement because it will be susceptible to SQL injections. You should: (1) escape your SQL statement or (2) use the ? placeholder.

(1) Escape

```
var a = 'AB1234';
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM orders WHERE cust = ' + mysql.escape(a);
con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(result);
});
```

(2) ? placeholder

```
var a = 'AB1234';
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM orders WHERE a = ?';
con.query(sql, [a], function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Yup, I was initially doing this but the point of the application is to demonstrate SQL injection, which is why I'm not escaping or using ? currently. Is there a way to just display the default SQLite error message when ' is entered instead?

Comment: Have you considered using try...catch and throw clauses?